# Pandas - Extracting value from a nested dict column

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe whose structure is as below. I am trying to extract value pertaining to a particular name.

I am trying to get the value corresponding name = `SLA Miss`. Expected output : `Not missed`

```
id, value
101, [{'compulsory_on_complete': True, 'name': 'Office Location', 'value': 'London', 'value_id': 2, 'type': 'choice'}, 
      {'compulsory_on_complete': True, 'name': 'Ticket Category', 'value': 'Incident', 'value_id': 5, 'type': 'choice'}, 
      {'compulsory_on_complete': True, 'name': 'Incident Type', 'value': 'Cache', 'value_id': 329, 'type': 'choice'}, 
      {'compulsory_on_complete': True, 'name': 'Cache Type', 'value': 'Redis', 'value_id': 344, 'type': 'choice'}, 
      {'compulsory_on_complete': True, 'name': 'Escalate to Owner', 'value': 'No', 'value_id': 390, 'type': 'choice'}, 
      {'compulsory_on_complete': True, 'name': 'SLA Miss', 'value': 'Not missed', 'value_id': 424, 'type': 'choice'}]
```

Comment: Could you add a few rows of your dataframe as a sample please.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
name = 'SLA Miss'
df = pd.DataFrame(value)
df.set_index('name').loc[name, 'value']
'Not missed'
```

With dict:

```
tmp_dict = dict(map(lambda x: (x['name'], x['value']), value))
tmp_dict[name]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Do we need to create a new Dataframe when the data is already is part of another Dataframe

Comment: You can use dict from native python but since you tagged it with pandas I thought you wanted to use data frames